# $_GET URL ReWriting

Tags: php, url, mod-rewrite

Hey everyone. Hopefully I can explain this correctly.

I have some URL's which I would like to tidy up through URL reWriting. For instance, I have:

```
domain.com/index.php?page=1
domain.com/index.php?page=2
domain.com/index.php?page=3
domain.com/index.php?page=4 etc..
```

which I would like to be shown in the URL as:

```
domain.com/page/1
domain.com/page/2
domain.com/page/3
domain.com/page/4 etc..
```

Also a quick question:
-Will the $_GET query's still be executed if the URL is rewritten?

Many thanks ahead of time. I have the modules enabled and the .htaccess is ready to go. i just need some direction. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add this to your .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^page/(\d+)/?$ /index.php?page=$1 [L]
```

The GET queries will always be executed. If the user types in `domain.com/index.php?page=3`, then `index.php` will run. If they type in `domain.com/page/3`, then mod_rewrite will convert it to `domain.com/index.php?page=3` before passing it to PHP. Either way, `index.php` is run.

Comment: Ah, you know what, it is. But it is doing the opposite of what I want. I want it so that if they type domain.com/index.php?page=3 it will redirect to domain.com/page/3

Comment: Actually, you know what... this is fine. I will just update my links to reflect these. Never mind this works perfect, thanks!

Comment: Just a small sidenote - I recommend adding a `/?` to the end of the first part your RewriteRule, e.g. `^page/(\d+)/?$`. Since this structure imitates directory-like appearance, both `domain.com/page/3` and `domain.com/page/3/` should be valid and should work.

Comment: Im still a bit confused? So if I have a link that is index.php?page=3
 and I want it to re-direct to index.php/page/3   is this how I would do it? I feel like this is backwards to what I want to do, or is i not?