# .htaccess RewriteRule and $_GET variable

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess

I'm working on a website and need to do some URL rewriting

It's very similar to [$_GET URL ReWriting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5188218/get-url-rewriting) but I can't seem to make it work

Basically in my `index.php` I'm using a `$_GET` variable to display content

```php
<?php
$page = basename($_GET['page']).".php";
if(file_exists("content/".$page))
    include("header.php");
else
    include("header_index.php");
?>

<div id="main">
<!-- container -->
    <?php
    if (file_exists("content/".$page))
        echo '<div id="container">';
    else
        echo '<div id="container" class="index_container">';
    ?>
        <!-- content -->
            <div id="content">
                <?php
                    if(file_exists("content/".$page))
                        include("content/".$page);
                    else
                        include("content/index_page.php");
                    include("./content/right_menu.php");
                ?>
            </div>
        <!-- content -->
    </div>
<!-- /container -->
</div>

<?php
    include("./footer.php");
?>
```

That way `test.com/?page=test1` displays `website_folder/content/test1.php`

What I'm trying to do is to make it to `test.com/test1`

All of the links on my pages are like `<a href="?page=testX">Test X</a>`

Thank you

edit : 
Rewrite rules tried
`RewriteRule (.*)$ ?page=$1`
`RewriteRule ./([a-zA-Z]+)$ ./index.php?page=$1`
`RewriteRule /([a-zA-Z0-9]) /?page=$1`
`RewriteRule ^subdomain.test.com/subfolder/(.+) subdomain.test.com/subfolder/index.html?page=$1 [NC]`
`RewriteRule (.+)$ index.php?page=$1`

Comment: What should I write in `.htaccess` to get `test.com/test1` instead of `test.com/?page=test1`?

Comment: Yes. It's like one of the most simple things, similar to what is explained in pretty much every single tutorial about mod_rewrite but it does not seem to work in my case. (Yes my host does allow URL rewriting and I know my `.htaccess` is taken into account)

Comment: Edited. Flags were `[NC]` most of the time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do:

```
RewriteRule ^subdomain.test.com/subfolder/(.+) subdomain.test.com/subfolder/index.html?page=$1 [NC]
```

It works for me!

(Note the .html. You may need to change it to .php, .asp ect.)

You will also need:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
```

Above the previous statement.

Comment: It doesn't seem to work here...
index actually is at subdomain.test.com/subfolder/index but it shouldn't change anything
`RewriteEngine on` was already there

`RewriteRule ^subdomain.test.com/subfolder/(.+) subdomain.test.com/subfolder/?page=$1 [NC]` did not work

Comment: I have updated the answer. If that doesn't work, could you give details about what happens when you try it?

Comment: I did try this earlier but it does not work either. Requesting `sub.test.com/subfolder/contact` makes me 404 but `sub.test.com/subfolder/?page=contact` correctly displays `website_folder/content/contact.php`.
All of the URL are still being displayed as `sub.test.com/sub/?page=pagename`

Comment: If that doesn't work, I don't think I can help you further. Sorry :(

Comment: No problem man, I'll try to find some way. I don't understand why it won't work either, your solution seems perfectly logic.
Thank you a lot for your help!