# Site structure with user friendly urls

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess, codeigniter, web

Okay, so I know this question title is a little vague and it has to have been answered before, but Ive spent hours looking at various solutions and none of them quite answer what im looking for.

Ok, so im making a site with a navigation structure resembling this -

#### Navigation Structure

```
Home
Products
    Overview
        Feature sub-page
        Feature sub-page
        Feature sub-page
    Videos
    Demonstrations
Training
...
```

So my idea so far is to have for a file structure:

#### File Structure

```
resources/
    config.php
public_html/
   index.php
   menu.php
   head.php
   footer.php
   css/
   images/
   js/
   pages/
       home/
           index.php
           home.php
       products/
           index.php
           sub-page.php
           sub-page.php
           videos.php
           demonstrations.php
       training/
           index.php
       ...
```

So Im using a config.php with path variables to maintain links.
And for each 'category' im using

```
pages/CATEGORY/index.php?page=XXX
```

What im really looking for is a way to structure my files or setup .htaccess so that it provides clean urls to look something like:

```
products home page -  mysite/products/
products video page - mysite/videos  OR  mysite/products/videos
products sub-pages -  mysite/products/sub-page
```

With the ability to mask my actual file structure and when pages like products/index.php has $_GET variables, to tanform the url into:

```
mysites/products/sub-page
```

Ive looked at mod_rewrite of course, and was thinking something like

```
RewriteRule products/sub-page products/index.php?page=sub-page-name
```

might work but wouldnt answer masking folder structure (ie. 'pages'). This would require at least one rule for each 'category' with regex

Just to clarify: all pages/categories/index.php contain all of the to level .php parts (head, menu, footer, ect) and the top level index.php just contains an include for pages/home/index.php

Note: I also need to support 404 pages into the sub-pages, so that if I do use

```
index.php?page=sub-page-name
```

And the sub-page doesnt actually exist, that it shows a valid message, or even just reverts to the default index.php content (conditional check on variables against existing files or 'approved values' list)

-EDIT-

So the solution im looking at now is:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/products/$ http://.../public_html/pages/products/index.php
RewriteRule ^(.*)/products/videos$ http://.../public_html/pages/products/index.php?page=videos
RewriteRule ^(.*)/products/demonstrations$ http://.../public_html/pages/products/index.php?page=demonstrations
```

But this only solves part of the problem (and is a bit too specific for my liking but i can bear with that if absolutely need be)

How about when im doing sub-pages, the number is fiarly large and potentially subject to change. Instead of doing 1 rule for each subpage could I use

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/products/info/(.*)$ http://.../public_html/pages/products/index.php?product=XXX
```

And even if I let the user pass in the variable '?product' themselves, would I write

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/products/?product(.*)$ http://.../public_html/pages/products/index.php?product=$1
```

or similar?

Also, I need this to work both ways, so that if they use the full url (ie. with `?page`) it changes to the masked url

-EDIT-

So im now using the CodeIgniter php framework, its a very light mvc framework which doesnt enforce too many strict rules upon you, it also allows me to place this in my routes.php:

```
$route['products/info/(:any)'] = "products/view_info/$1";
$route['(:any)/(:any)'] = "$1/view/$2";
$route['(:any)'] = "$1/view";
```

which, when combined with this in my .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT,L]
```

solves my issues.

Im not using it too strickly right now, still have a mess of javascript controlling my youtubeapi requests within my videos.php page, but i may convert this to a model.php and jquery ajax hybred, if i can get my model.php to easily intrigrate without causing me to rewrite all of my api-handling code to php

Comment: try this hope help you. stackoverflow.com/questions/15723942/rewriting-an-apache-redirect-rule/15724022#15724022

Comment: sorry, i tried it but its not what im looking for.
I tweaked it and had my url being changed, but its actually changing whre the browser is directing to.
I just want to obscure/mask the variables and the 'pages' parts, but still return the correct response.

Maybe im just doing it wrong ;)

Comment: ok.but first my english is not so good. and then what you want to do just remove .php?

Comment: no, that too but im really looking to set it so that my user only ever sees the path i want - ie. mysite/products/sub-page - when the request is in fact - mysite/pages/products/index.php?page=sub-page-name - 

This seems to be exactly what mod_rewrite helps do, ive looked at the actual mod_rewrite doco though and still cant get it working as I want.

Im also open to changing the file structure and such if it will help, but I still need to be able to mask my actual request url

Comment: ok Im not very good with htaccess but i know a way you can do it with php and a simple htaccess(that I know that). this way is called one entry point. in this way you make just one entry point and you can right functions that checks anything or change anything before a user can see the page (even IP blocking)

Comment: I found 
[link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5188218/get-url-rewriting?rq=1 
which seems to be answering my variable passing problem but i cant get it to work.

`RewriteRule ^(.*)/products/info/(\d+)/?$ http://.../public_html/pages/products/index.php?product=$1 [L]`

Comment: Quickly checked out entry points, not sure if thats actually what im looking for as there seems to only be 1 entry point and I would have to restructure my includes to all run from index.php, which doesnt at all answer the question of masking.

Again, I only looked briefly so feel free to correct me

Comment: @Damascus Since you found your own solution, you can write it up as an actual answer and accept it, even thought it's your own! This helps keep Stack Overflow clean, rather than confusing what is a question vs an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Make the top index.php control all the pages. So /products/sub-page would be rewritten to /index.php?page=%2Fproducts%2Fsub-page. I think your rewrite rule would look something like this:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?page=$1
```

Then your index.php would look something like this:

```
include( 'pages'.$_GET['page'] );
```

You may need to have a few rules ahead of it to exclude doing the rewrite for your css, images, and javascript.

Comment: Thanks @Marshmellow1328
So the rule `RewriteRule ^(.*)/products/$ http://localhost/.../public_html/pages/products/index.php` works but requires a great deal of specificity.

Im really looking for something more flexible

Comment: What about RewriteRule ^/(.*)/(.*) /pages/$1/$2? So /products/sub-page gets sent to /pages/products/sub-page.

Comment: How would I define this rule, can you please provide both parameters for the RewriteRule as an example?

Comment: That is the RewriteRule. "RewriteRule &/(.*)/(.*) /pages/$1/$2"

Comment: I've updated my original answer with slightly more details. It's essentially the same as imsiso's. There are no special rules per page. This handles all of your pages. Give it a shot and let us know what problems you are having with it. I know it works because I have an app that does this very thing.